# Use user code in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin which need to use a piece of code written by the user.

Basically my plugin is launching a thread (by means of a command), which uses reflection for instantiating a set of classes defined in a text file. The problem is that these classes can be provided by the user, hence their path is not known a priori.

There are two possible scenarios:

- The user develop the code as a java project
- The user provide a jar containing the implementation of the classes

My plugin should be able to access and use these classes.

I guess that the best solution would be being able of setting the plugin class-path at runtime.
Less nice, but better than nothing, would be defining a standard folder in which the user has to store his jar files.

Is there a solution to this problem?